# Ways of defining a field in Django form

Tags: python, django

I am defining a field in a django form in the following two ways :

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(u.id,u.username) for u in User.objects.filter(type="TYPE1")])
```

OR

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    pass

    def_init_(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(MyForm,self)._init_(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(u.id,u.username) for u in User.objects.filter(type="TYPE1")])
```

Is there any different between these two approaches?? I tried to find this on web but did not get any relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a special field to handle such things - [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

In your example the difference is the moment when code is executed.

In first approach it is executed when module with form is loaded, in second - every time the form is initialized (so basically on each request to your view). So first approach has a problem - Users will be loaded on first request. If any user registers after this moment - he will not be present in the select field until you restart the server.

Also I think it is a bad practice to introduce new field in `__init__` method. If you really need something like this and you can't use `ModelChoiceField` the better way is

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(MyForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'].choices = [(u.id, u.username) for u in User.objects.filter(type="TYPE1")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you get an error when you run your server using the first way?

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(u.id,u.username) for u in User.objects.filter(type="TYPE1")])
```

If you use this method That `for` will be executed when the file is being read. Try using the second way or a function to execute that `for` and set the choices.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in `Form.__init__` you define some dynamic fields (for example, you want to show some checkboxes, which are set/unset according to the data from some model). In all other cases first approach is better because it's more readable.